# Angular(Type script) - How to add If condition inside an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am displaying buttons on the screen by fetching the buttons to displayed by calling a method which looks as below

```
getButtons: IGetButtonsList = {
  "Buttons": [
     {
       "DisplayName": "Create User",
       "Target": "./createuser"
     },
     {
       "DisplayName": "Load Products",
       "Target": "./getproducts/all"
     }
  ]
};
```

I want to add a condition inside the array **if this.role === 'WL_H3G'** i want to stop returning 'Create User' button item from the array. I have access to this.role property on the component ts file

I tried adding the condition check if this.role === 'WL_H3G inside the array but it is throwing compile errors.

Comment: *"by calling a method that looks as below..."* That is clearly no method.

Comment: Arrays are for storing data, not logic. You will have to add your check for a specific `role` either in the HTML template or elsewhere in your TypeScript with a method that only returns the array items you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine the Props to make it accept undefined type (Note that remember to check the condition in HTML to not cause the error when rendering.

Since the `this.role` is fetch from API, careful that the `getButtons` make not return the right value you want since `getButtons` is defined before `this.role` has value.

```
getButtons: IGetButtonsList = {
  "Buttons": [
      this.role === 'WL_H3G'?undefined:{
       "DisplayName": "Create User",
       "Target": "./createuser"
     },
     {
       "DisplayName": "Load Products",
       "Target": "./getproducts/all"
     }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread syntax to eliminate elements in the array based on condition:

```
const optionalButtons = [{
       "DisplayName": "Create User",
       "Target": "./createuser"
     }]
getButtons: IGetButtonsList = {
  "Buttons": [
     ...(this.role == "WL_H3G" ? [] : optionalButtons),
     {
       "DisplayName": "Load Products",
       "Target": "./getproducts/all"
     }
  ]
};
```

Here, the `spread` operator (`...`) unpacks the elements in the array which is calculated using the condition `this.role == "WL_H3G"`.
This means that if the condition returns `true`, no elements will be added to the array, otherwise `optionalButtons` elements will be added